# Transpose irregular matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I got this matrix that, depending on the results I receive from the server, the width can change. Basically, it can be something like

```
[undefined, undefined]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2]
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and I want it to be like this

```
[undefined, 1, 1, undefined, 1]
[undefined, 2, 2, undefined, 2]
[undefined, 3,undefined, undefined, 3]
[undefined, 4, undefined, undefined, 4]
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 5]
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 6]
```

Notice that the height changed to the maximum width of the first example.
I googled it and the best solution I got was this

```
array.map((row, i) => array.map(col => col[i]))
```

but this solution wont change my matrix height. I tried 2 for cycles but I think I didn't code it right as I was not getting the expected result.
If someone could give me a little help, that would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to solve this (as other answers demonstrate). Here's how I'd do it, as it minimizes the number of times we iterate over the data.

```js
const data = [
  [undefined, undefined],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
];

// get the length of the longest array
const maxLen = data.reduce((max, {length}) => Math.max(max, length), 0);

// make a new set of arrays
const result = Array.from({ length: maxLen }, (_, i) => data.map(col => col[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you called the _map_ iterated element _row_ instead of _col_
`data.map(row => row[i])`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps involved here.

1. Find the max length.
2. Normalise
3. And then rotate

I've placed comments in code to show each part.

```js
const input = [
  [undefined, undefined],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2],
  [undefined, undefined, undefined],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
];

//first find max length
const maxw = Math.max(...input.map(m => m.length));

//now normalize
const norm_inputs = input.map(m => 
  (new Array(maxw)).concat(m).slice(-maxw)
);

//now rotate..
const output = (new Array(maxw).fill(0)).map(
  (row, i) => norm_inputs.map(col => col[i]))
```

Comment: Your solution almost worked but even though the matrix had the height expected, it still only got the number of elements of the input matrix height.

Comment: @tiagomnf I had put -6 for the slice instead of -maxw, try now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your matrix is stored in `matrix`,

```
const transformed = [];

const maxWidth = matrix.reduce((max, current) => {
    return (current.length > max) ? current.length : max;
}, 0);

// Loop over each column
for (let i = 0; i < maxWidth; i++) {
    const tRow = [];

    // Loop over each row of the current column
    for (const row of matrix) {
        tRow.push(row[i]);
    }

    transformed.push(tRow);
}
```